# WPF Prism error while showing a Window include a Region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-4

I'm working on my `WPF` `Prism` application and trying to show some of my different `Views` in a `Region`. So i use the following code **in my `Shell.xaml`** and it works well (it shows multiple view under each-other).

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion" Width="400"/>
```

I have an another `Window` named `WinExtra.xaml`. My application creates an instance of it at `Run-Time` when user click on a `Button` in `Shell.xaml`.

Inside the `WinExtra` i have some `TabControl` and inside theme i keep my `UserControls`.

Now i want to put the same `Region` like above inside one of these `UserControls`. so i write the above code again but this time **inside `WinExtra.xaml> TabControl1> TabItem1> UserControl1.xaml`**:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion" Width="400"/>
```

**But** after i create an instance of `WinExtra` **`on Showing`** it, i get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Behaviors.**RegionCreationException**'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: An exception occurred while creating a region
>   with name 'WorkspaceRegion'. The exception was:
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: **The IRegionAdapter
>   for the type System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl is not registered in
>   the region adapter mappings**. You can register an IRegionAdapter for
>   this control by overriding the ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method
>   in the bootstrapper.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings.GetMapping(Type
>   controlType)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Behaviors.DelayedRegionCreationBehavior.CreateRegion(DependencyObject
>   targetElement, String regionName).

**Note:** I use `MahApps.Metro` in this project. and all window types are `controls:MetroWindow`

- What is the reason of the above Error?
- How can i solve it?

Comment: I founded the error reason & solved it. I was loading Prism dll assembly too during loading my module assembly after showing shell. Now i prevent this prism dll loading and have not any `RegionCreationException` in my project

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had a reference to the old Prism.Composition package which caused a conflict. A simple `Uninstall-Package Prism.Composition <Project> -Force` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the error reason & solved it.

I was loading Prism dll assembly during loading my module assembly after showing shell.

Now i prevent this prism dll loading and have not any `RegionCreationException` in my project

Comment: Hi, Could you share details of how did you prevent the Prism dll?